# Wilcard routing to methods with params in mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create wildcard routes in a test MVC 6 Web API project. But I'm not sure how to do this. I currently have this in my `Controller` class.

```
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet("{*anything:regex(^(.*)?$)}")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{*anything}/{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

If I only have the first `Get()` in my `Controller` then it works. But, when I add the second `Get(int id)` method, then I get an `Internal Server Error`. In fact, it's the `[HttpGet("{*anything}/{id}")]` line that causes the trouble above the second `Get` method.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> In fact, it's the [HttpGet("{*anything}/{id}")] line that causes the
>   trouble above the second Get method.

As far as i know, wildcard segment ({*anything}) can be only last segment into a route template.

Therefore you can't use template with {id} segment after {*anything}.

I suggest you [enable logging](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html) in your application, the most errors show there.